# Size Class Design for Iphone and Ipad

Tags: ios7, ios8, autolayout, size-classes

I have to support both Landscape and Potrait for Iphone and Landscape for Ipad respectively, Under Size classes is it a necessary that i have to start with **AnyAny** first for basic layout and then proceed with **compactwidth** & **RegularHeight** for support Potrait orientation for Iphone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't really matter as for each size class you can set installed (as if, active constraint that will be fulfilled) constraints and which will be uninstalled ( disabled ). Just make sure that you don't have overlapping constraints and you are good to go. For more reference there is a great article: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50319/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-2

Also they have a book about iOS 8 and there you can find even more information.